# Accessing counts in State Monad haskell

Tags: haskell, state, monads

I have this

```
newtype State' s a = State' { runState' :: (s, Counts) -> (a, s, Counts) }
```

Now i want to write a function

```
getCounts :: State' s a -> Counts
```

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: I guess you want something like this: `getCounts :: State' s Counts`? (before you *run* your state computation you cannot possible know the counts - so you might want to query the count from inside the state instead?)

Comment: I edited the question. But how do I access the Counts?

Comment: @CarstenKönig I think it'd be `getCounts :: State' s Counts`, to be more precise.

Comment: @bheklilr sorry - yes of course

Comment: @CarstenKönig Counts is a Monoid consisting of 4 differen Ints

Comment: what about `getCounts = State' (\ (s,c) -> (c,s,c))` ?

Comment: Wouldn't `State' s a ~ State (s, Counts) a` where `State` is from `Control.Monad.State`?  I'd suggest looking at how `get` is implemented for that monad to get some ideas.

Comment: @dosmath it does not really matter what `Counts` is if you just want to get it from the state - it's really only *another* `s` in there (I think this is what bheklilr wanted to say too)

Comment: @CarstenKönig now the getCounts function returns a State' s Counts. Should I now write a evalState' to get the Counts?

Comment: @dosmath - yes if you give me *your* definition of `evalState'` I'll add it to the answer - I think this is easier than doing it in comment-chat-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
getCounts :: State' s Counts
getCounts = State' (\ (s,c) -> (c,s,c))
```

you can then use it inside a computation:

```
myStateComp = do
  -- whaever
  counts <- getCounts
  -- ...
```

and yes you can `eval` it too

assuming your `evalState'` is something like this:

```
evalState' :: State' s a -> s -> Counts -> a
evalState' st initState initCounts = 
    let (a,_,_) = runState st (initState,initCounts)
    in a
```

then you can get to the Counts like this:

```
evalState' getCounts initState initCount
```

of course this just gives you back `initCount` - but without any more computation I don't see what else I could answer.

A real example might be something like this:

```
myComp = do
  -- ... do comp
  getCounts
```

and then

```
evalState' myComp initState initCount
```

will run any computation inside and then return the last count

### alternative

the alternative @bheklilr was hinting at is using

```
import Control.Monad.State

type State' s a = State (s, Counts) a
```

and:

```
myStateComp = do
  -- whaever
  (state,counts) <- get
  -- ...
```

so your `getCounts` here is really just `fmap snd get`

Comment: Ok, but how do I use this when I need to write a function that
returns (a,Counts). If I understand correctly, now I can only access the Counts in a do block?

Comment: you use your eval with an initial state